# Ways to reduce polynomial modulus irreducible polynomial in F_2

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, modules

Thank you all in advance for the help. I really appreciate your time in answering this question.

---

I am trying to find a good summary of ways to reduce polynomial modules irreducible polynomial in $F_2$. Examples of exercise I have run through are:

---

> $x^{21}$ mod $x^5+x+1$

can be solved by fast exponentiation as follow

> $x^{21}=((x^5)^2)^2 x=((x+1)^2)^2x=(x^4+1)x=x^5+x=1$ mod $x^5+x+1$

---

However, when I try to solve

> $x^{31}$ mod $x^5+x^2+1$

the same method doesn't work.

I do notice that it may be easier to solve instead

> $x^{32}$ mod $x^5+x^2+1$

then multiply by multiplicative inverse of x found by Euclidean algorithm. But even this I failed to solve.

---

My questions are:

1. How would you solve the second case?
2. Is there a robust method I can follow in solving this kind of reductions besides instincts and trials-and-errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fermat's Little Theorem applies to finite fields: If $K$ is a field with $q$ elements, then $a^q = a$ for all $a\in K$.

Since $\mathbb{F}_p [X] / f(x)$ is a field of $p^{\deg f}$ elements when $f$ is irreducible, we can apply this to your example.

In particular, we have $x^{32} = x^{2^5} \equiv x \pmod{x^5+x+1}$.  Dividing, we have $x^{31} = x^{-1} x^{32} \equiv x^{-1} x \equiv 1$.

Comment: Little Theorem, yes...takes 10 seconds at most. Thank you, this is the piece I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

[Polynomial long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division), and its relative, [synthetic division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division).

For any polynomials $f$ and $g$ (regardless of whether they're irreducible), computing $f$ modulo $g$ is the same as computing the remainder when $f$ is divided by $g$; or to put it another way, it is the same as computing the unique $r$ with $\deg(r)<\deg(g)$ such that $f=qg+r$ for some $q$.

Comment: This will take a long time for the problems listed..

Comment: You didn't specify anything about speed in your question - besides, a computer will do it for you easily.

Comment: The question is looking for an algebraic method that takes a reasonable amount of time for the examples. Perhaps you do not agree with me..